# Treat Laravel multi auth users as a unique user class

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5, orm, eloquent

I have been struggling with this problem for couple of days and I've searched everywhere but couldn't find a logical solution.

I need multiple types of users in my project(admin, customer) because I need completely different backend logic for each type. So I decided to use multi-auth method in laravel(which AFAIK is the best solution for these cases). So I have multiple user classes for each type(and multiple tables in DB) including `Admin` and `User` classes. `AdminAuth` and `UserAuth` classes manage the Login and Register logic and routes are handled using middlewares.

Up till now there is no problem. The problem is that I need to use a single user class in another classes. For example consider the messaging logic(and there are many many similar use cases):

a Message class Model should have:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'from_id', 'to_id', 'content', 'state'
];

 public function sender(){
     return $this->belongsTo(**User::class**);
 }

 public function receiver(){
     return $this->belongsTo(**User::class**);
 }
 ...
```

In the above model, I need to specify the **User::class** for senders and receivers, which can be either admins or users. So how can I tell Eloquent to use both models. Is it even possible? If not, what is the solution here?

I thought of using a higher level class named Person, for example, to hold the Admin or User object instances, but this way ORM can't manage to retrieve or store users from/in the appropriate tables automatically.

Any Suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to use the following guidelines to handle such functionality; create a model for each user type but all of them should have a relationship with Laravel's default user class by keeping the user's id. Also, keep general properties in the user class and specific properties in each sub class, like customer's can have addresses and admins can have phone numbers, while the common things like the username can be kept in the user model. Then you won't need multiply forms for login, when a user logs in, you redirectly accordingly to the user's type in the default user record. Now for your messaging problem, use user the default user model to establish the relationship in messages as you shown above. Then defenping on the user's type, grant him different priviledges or features in the chat.